# How to perform one of the MongoDB aggregation stage only under certain condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

### Is there any way I can ommit one of the MongoDB aggregation stages if certain condition evaluates to true or false?

I'm building the restaurant searcher app, where you can find restaurant by the name, cuisine they serve etc. One of the fields that user can type in is the restaurant `name` field. If the user leaves it empty I want to not to perform the `$text` search on the name field but I do not know how can I achieve it.

Here is my sample code, that however is not working becouse it bumps the alert `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $cond`.

```
const { borough, cuisine, name } = req.body;

  try {
    const restaurantCollection = databaseFunctions
      .getDatabase()
      .collection('restaurants');
    const fetchedRestaurants = await restaurantCollection
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $ne: [name, ''] },
                  then: { $text: { $search: name } },
                  else: null,
                },
              },
              { borough: { $in: borough } },
              { cuisine: { $in: cuisine } },
            ],
          },
        }]
  } catch {...}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

First look at your error `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $cond`, the [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) is a aggregation expression, you need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#using-expr-with-conditional-statements) before `$and` operation,

Second you can not use `$text` search inside any expression look at more about [$text restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#restrictions), my suggestion it is better you can check empty `name` condition in client side.

Comment: So if I ever want to perform some type of aggregation operation only under some condition using this pattern: $expr: {$cond: {...}}, would be the good idea?

Comment: I tried to use the same code as you specified in your answer however it shows the error with the message: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$text'

Comment: Okay, yes sorry i forgot to look into $text, might be you can not use $text inside any expression, there are many [restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#restrictions), please look into it. i am looking if is there any solutions, otherwise i will update my answer to right direction.

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally managed problem with my code on my own.
I moved my aggregation pipeline to the another constant (named `aggregationPipeline`). Then if the `name` variable is not empty I'm using the array unshift method to add the `$text` agregation stage to my pipline. I know that it is pretty simple but it took me some time to figure it out. Here is my code. If you have the better solution guys, please post it.

```
const aggregationPipeline = [
    // all my others aggregation pipeline stages
  ];

  if (name)
    aggregationPipeline.unshift({ $match: { $text: { $search: name } } });
```